# Dynamic data store in database using Jquery brackets

Tags: jquery

Its my first time i m going to make a [bracket system](http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/). So i google for jquery bracket system. i found a link for this purpose. and useful for static functionality.

I am using the following code to make bracket system.

```
var customData = {
    teams : [
      [{name: "Team 1", flag: 'gg'}, {name: "Team 2", flag: 'gg'}],
      [{name: "Team 3", flag: 'gg'}, {name: "Team 4", flag: 'gg'}]
    ],
    results : [4,2]
  }

/* Edit function is called when team label is clicked */
function edit_fn(container, data, doneCb) {
  var input = $('<input type="text">')
  input.val(data.name)
  container.html(input)
  input.focus()
  input.blur(function() { doneCb({flag: data.flag, name: input.val()}) })
}

/* Render function is called for each team label when data is changed, data
 * contains the data object given in init and belonging to this slot. */
function render_fn(container, data, score) {
  if (!data.flag || !data.name)
    return
  container.append('<img src="images/'+data.flag+'.png" /> ').append(data.name)
}

$(function() {

  $('#customHandlers .demo').bracket({
    init: customData,
    save: function(){}, /* without save() labels are disabled */
    decorator: {edit: edit_fn,
                render: render_fn}})

});
```

Working good but i want to store the results to database dynamically. 
Because i am new i don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is a bracket system? Do you have any preference for the database? (MySQL, Azure?)

Comment: That's the bracket system. http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/
nope! i don't have any preference.

Comment: Mybe take a look at this for storage: http://www.taffydb.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Save the date from jquery bracket json request...**

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);

$sql = "INSERT into table_name SET 
teams='".serialize($data->teams)."',result='".serialize($data->results)."'";
```

**Get the data of bracket from database**

```
"SELECT * from table_name"; 

$teams=unserialize($resultr['teams']);
$result=unserialize($resultr['result']);


**Populate in the jquery bracket data...** 

var saveData = {
    teams : 
       echo json_encode($teams); 
    ,
    results : 
      echo json_encode($result); 
        };
```

https://github.com/hassamSatti/hassamSatti.git

Answer (score 0):

Because this is your first time working with Databases and it seems you want to go down the JavaScript route for your first development project, I suggest you to check out MongoDB.

For your application it also seems like a perfekt fit as MongoDB stores JSON Data, just like your Braket system.

You can check it out here:

https://www.mongodb.com/de-de/what-is-mongodb

or here

https://university.mongodb.com/

They also offer a free teer in their cloud service, wich is perfect to learn how everything works.

Basicly you need only 2 things to get started with MongoDB:

- A MongoDB Server
- A JavaScript library (e.g. mongoose) to connect to your server